# Unable to Terminate NSRunningApplication

Tags: swift, macos

Simple Hello World MacOS app with an updated ViewController file.

```
//  ViewController.swift

import Cocoa
import AppKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.quitVLC()
    }

    func quitVLC() {
        for app in NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications as [NSRunningApplication] {
            if let appName = app.localizedName, appName == "VLC" {
                app.forceTerminate()
                print(app.isTerminated)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When in debug mode, the execution get's to the forceTerminate command, but it always prints false, and never terminates the app.

Ideas?

Comment: Could be a sandbox issue.

Answer (score 3):

Had to turn off sandbox mode in the Capabilities section of the Project Settings.